# Internationalize python shared project

Tags: python, internationalization

I'm relatively new to python. I'm developing three applications, one of them is a requirement for the other two, with common string constants, models, tool functions... The three of them will we installed in the same machine, but one of them needs to load the strings of the shared project in English and the other one in Spanish. I've googled a lot but can't find an answer that fit my needs. What do you think would be the best aproach? I'm using python 2.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary in the shared library: `{'english':value, 'spanish':value}`.

Comment: a dictionary `my_var={'spanish':'adios','english':'bye'}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary in the shared library like:

```
d = {'english':"English string", 'spanish':"Spanish string"}
```

Then access it with:

```
lang = 'english'
d[lang]  # gives "English string"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to go with [gettext](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gettext.html). You prepare translation files in different languages, configure a language for every application and use gettext API to get translations.